# Is the letter Aleph (א) also a word that means "to teach, inculcate"?

Tags: hebrew, language, aleph-bet-letters

[This](http://www.aish.com/sp/ph/48956911.html) Aish article about the meaning of the word "Adam"  states the following:

> The letter *aleph* is also a word which means to teach or inculcate.   It similarly indicates leadership, as implied by the related word *aluf* which means a general or tribal head.

A quick search of translate.google.com did not verify this statement.  Neither does the [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/aleph), though it did (suprisingly, as it's an English dictionary) verified that the word origin suggests leadership based on the word *aluf.*

Is the source correct?  Is the letter Aleph (א) also a word that means "to teach, inculcate"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Indeed it does!

One source in Tanach that illustrates this is [Iyov 33:33](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Iyyov/33.33#e0n7):

> אִם־אַ֭יִן אַתָּ֥ה שְֽׁמַֽע־לִ֑י הַ֝חֲרֵ֗שׁ **וַאֲאַלֶּפְךָ֥** חׇכְמָֽה׃
>
> If not, hearken thou unto me; Hold thy peace, **and I will teach thee** wisdom. (JPS translation)

Metzudos and Ralbag translate it this way here, and and I see no dissenters.  Metzudos references [Iyov 15:5](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Iyyov/15.5#e0n7) and [Mishlei 22:25](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Mishlei/22.25#e0n7) (where Rashi also translates this way).

(BTW, I don't know Iyov/Mishlei well, I just remembered it from [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6372&st=&pgnum=127), second to last line.)

---

H/t to Loewian, who noted that Aleph also means "to teach" in Aramaic, as noted by Jastrow and others, from Targum Kesuvim to Mishlei 11:25, as well as various other sources:

> נֶֽפֶשׁ־בְּרָכָ֥ה תְדֻשָּׁ֑ן **וּ֝מַרְוֶ֗ה גַּם־ה֥וּא יוֹרֶֽא**
>
> נַפְשָׁא דְבִרְכְּתָא תִדְהַן **וּמַן דִמְאַלֵף אַף הוּא יֵלִיף**

Comment: So too in Aramaic

Comment: @Loewian I had assumed that it was somehow related to "learning out" words, like  "יליף"/"למילף".

Comment: I thought Yalif was "go" as in "in a certain direction. A person can physically go, or be taught in a certain path (or be led down that path by a leader) I guess.